# Select on name in object

Tags: jquery, json

First of all I'm still learning so please be gentle :)
I have a json response where I want to select some specific elements. 
I'm trying to get some elements with a specific name inside an object and want to test if it matches a predefined name. These are product specifications with a specific name like "length", "width" etc.

I'm having trouble to find those specific names and if they are found get their "value" attribute.

So what I have is this:

JSON response:

```
{

"product": {
     "specs": {

       "231638": {
         "id": 231638,
         "title": "Length (mm)",
         "value": "1200"
     },
     "231641": {
         "id": 231641,
         "title": "Width (mm)",
         "value": "800"
     },
         "231644": {
         "id": 231644,
         "title": "Height (mm)",
         "value": "144"
     } //etc etc
```

Now I want to grab only the two `value` attributes from specifications "length" and "height". So first I have to look if those two names are present and matches "length" and "height" and if so grab their `value` attributes. That's where I need some help.

The end result must be

```
<div class="somediv">
 <span class="width">1200</span>
 <span class="height">144</span>
</div>
```

So what I have is this:

```
$.getJSON(url', function(data){
         var specsHtml = [];

      $.each(data.product.specs, function(index, spec){
        // in here I need to test if the name of the spec equals "length or Height". 
        specsHtml.push(spec.value);
       });
       specsHtml = specsHtml.join('');  
      }
  container.find('.product-bottom .measurements span').html(specsHtml);
 });
```

I'm completly stuck in here. I have tried things like:

```
(spec.hasOwnProperty("title"));
```

or

```
 var specs = [];
        data.product.specs.forEach(data.product.specs => {
        if (data.product.specs)
        for (var spec in data.product.specs)
            specs.push(spec);
        })
```

Any help greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var data = {
  "product": {
    "specs": {
      "231638": {
        "id": 231638,
        "title": "Length (mm)",
        "value": "1200"
      },
      "231641": {
        "id": 231641,
        "title": "Width (mm)",
        "value": "800"
      },
      "231644": {
        "id": 231644,
        "title": "Height (mm)",
        "value": "144"
      } //etc etc
    }
  }
};

var length = 0, width = 0, height = 0,
  reLength = /length/i,
  reWidth = /width/i,
  reHeight = /height/i;
$.each(data.product.specs, function (specId, spec) {
  if (reLength.test(spec.title))
    length = spec.value;
  else if (reWidth.test(spec.title))
    width = spec.value;
  else if (reHeight.test(spec.title))
    height = spec.value;
});

var html = '<div class="somediv">' +
  '<span class="width">w: ' + width + '</span>' +
  '<span class="height">h: ' + height + '</span>' +
  '<span class="length">l: ' + length + '</span>' +
  '</div>';
$(document.body).html(html);
```

```css
.somediv > span { padding: 10px;  display:inline-block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thx for your answer.! However this keeps returning "0" for all fields. Can you also please explain what '/length/i' does?

Comment: Ok I think I see what's going wrong. Your testing `spec.title` with that regEx, eg width. However that will always be false since it need to be compared with the `value name` of that spec. Can you help on that?

Comment: @Meules, I've replaced the code with a runnable snippet. Check it out

Comment: Ok I get it now :) That Regex looks for part of the name and not the full name! It works now... many thx!

Answer (score 1):

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data){
         var specsHtml = "<div class="somediv">";

      $.each(data.product.specs, function(){
        //'this' is now your current 'spec' which is { "id": ..., "title": ..., etc. }
        specsHtml += '<span class=\"';
        if (this.title.includes('Length'))
          specsHtml += 'length';
        else
          specsHtml += 'width';

        specsHtml = specsHtml + '\">' + this.value + '</span>';
       });
        specsHtml += '</div>';
      }
  container.find('.product-bottom .measurements span').html(specsHtml);
 });
```