# Test name in object

Tags: jquery, json

With the help of [this forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40178620/select-on-name-in-object/40178853?noredirect=1#comment67629374_40178853) I'm building a little script that test if a name is present in an object from a json response. If that name is present then I want to grab the value from that object and show it somewhere in a div.

Everything works perfectly, however there are some `product.specs` with almost identical names. In the example below we have:

`Height (mm)` and `Height stacked (mm)`.

When both of the above are present in the json response then it automatically grabs the second `Height` (so Height stacked (mm)).

When using the script below it test the name for `reHeight = /height/i;`. How can I rule out `Height stacked (mm)` from that test on only use the value from `Height (mm)`?

So what I have is this

```
var data = {
  "product": {
    "specs": {
      "231638": {
        "id": 231638,
        "title": "Length (mm)",
        "value": "1200"
      },
      "231641": {
        "id": 231641,
        "title": "Width (mm)",
        "value": "800"
      },
      "231644": {
        "id": 231644,
        "title": "Height (mm)",
        "value": "144"
      },
     "239999": {
        "id": 239999,
        "title": "Height stacked (mm)",
        "value": "14400"
      } //etc etc
    }
  }
};

var length = 0, width = 0, height = 0,
  reLength = /length/i,
  reWidth = /width/i,
  reHeight = /height/i;

$.each(data.product.specs, function (specId, spec) {
  if (reLength.test(spec.title))
    length = spec.value;
  else if (reWidth.test(spec.title))
    width = spec.value;
  else if (reHeight.test(spec.title))
    height = spec.value;
});

var html = '<div class="somediv">' +
  '<span class="width">w: ' + width + '</span>' +
  '<span class="height">h: ' + height + '</span>' +
  '<span class="length">l: ' + length + '</span>' +
  '</div>';
$(document.body).html(html);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can be more specific with regex:

> ```
> reHeight = /height \(mm\)/i;
> ```

```js
var data = {
  "product": {
    "specs": {
      "231638": {
        "id": 231638,
        "title": "Length (mm)",
        "value": "1200"
      },
      "231641": {
        "id": 231641,
        "title": "Width (mm)",
        "value": "800"
      },
      "231644": {
        "id": 231644,
        "title": "Height (mm)",
        "value": "144"
      },
     "239999": {
        "id": 239999,
        "title": "Height stacked (mm)",
        "value": "14400"
      } //etc etc
    }
  }
};

var length = 0, width = 0, height = 0,
  reLength = /length/i,
  reWidth = /width/i,
  reHeight = /height \(mm\)/i;

$.each(data.product.specs, function (specId, spec) {
  if (reLength.test(spec.title))
    length = spec.value;
  else if (reWidth.test(spec.title))
    width = spec.value;
  else if (reHeight.test(spec.title))
    height = spec.value;
});

var html = '<div class="somediv">' +
  '<span class="width">w: ' + width + '</span>' +
  '<span class="height">h: ' + height + '</span>' +
  '<span class="length">l: ' + length + '</span>' +
  '</div>';
$(document.body).html(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You were on the right track you just got your escapes reversed. Happy coding.;)